# Travis CI: clang deduces copy constructor when it should deduce move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, travis-ci, move-constructor

[I've edited this question as I simplified the example causing the issue]

I'm getting the following error on Travis CI (dist: trusty) with clang 3.9:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Foo'
                : foo{move(_foo)},
                  ^     [in a constructor member initialiser list]

note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'Foo' has a user-declared move constructor
            Foo(Foo&&) = default;
```

`move(_foo)` is *clearly* an xvalue -- why is the copy constructor being called?

What's particularly odd is that compiling with clang 3.9 works on my local machine. I am setting -std=c++11. I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you include constructors of the form `Foo(const B &) = delete;` and `Foo(B &&) {/*...*/}`?

Comment: I tried `Foo(const B &) = delete;` with `Foo(B &&);` (because there were a lot of members to initialise) and it still causes the same error.

Comment: PS. What I really don't understand is why the same compiler on the same OS is producing different results under travis...

Comment: cv-qualifiers perhaps?

Comment: @o11c: see below.  I needed to update the libraries.

Comment: @Mohan maybe you should always use libc++ with clang?

Comment: @o11c At the moment I'm struggling to get it working even with gcc. The problem is now that the version of boost on Travis is v. old.

Comment: @Mohan which libs? Since C++11 was released, boost doesn't have nearly as many *useful* libraries left ... a few are stable, and others (e.g. Spirit) should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @o11c boost::optional.

Comment: @Mohan ah, which is in C++17 as `std::optional`, or earlier as `std::experimental::optional`.

Comment: @o11c I don't want to use C++14 -- too new, which causes further problems.  Also I find `nullopt` _much_ less readable than `none`.

BTW, I _think_ SO always notifies the original poster, so you can omit the '@Mohan'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with g++ 4.8, indicating it was a problem with the libraries. And indeed,

> trusty [...] uses gcc-4 series standard library and is not C++11 conforming.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6300#issue-165225842